# Visual Studio "Search Solution Explorer" is disabled

Tags: visual-studio, solution-explorer

In Visual Studio 2015, every now and then my "Search Solution Explorer" is disabled.  Doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to it, and often restarting Visual Studio or loading a different project does not help.  I don't see anyone else on the internet complaining about this.  Anyone run into this and have a fix?

[image]

I do have Resharper installed, and perhaps that's causing problems, though I believe I've run into this before I ever installed Resharper.

Alternatively, is there a third party extension I can install in Visual Studio 2015 to search by filename?

Comment: (ctrl ,) does not work?

Comment: But sometimes restarting VS helps.

Comment: If you have Resharper, Ctrl-Shift-T will do better filename search, then VS.

Answer (score 26):

Renaming the `.suo` file worked for a colleague just now.

Comment: This also worked for me.  It was found in a directory in the .vs directory that contained the .sln file

Comment: Unfortunatelly does not solve my problem in VS2017 RTM 15.1

Comment: For VS 2015 the `.suo` can be found in `.vs\[project name]\.suo`. Delete and restart VS.

Answer (score 12):

Delete the "**.vs/projectname**" folder from the "**solutionname.sln**" directory and restart visual studio should work.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, many thanks! I think this is the correct answer fro "newer" Visual Studio versions. Since I have no ".suo" file. Visual Studio 2015 here :)