# Search Solution Explorer greyed out

Tags: visual-studio, solution-explorer

Suddenly the Search Solution Explorer field became grayed out. Not sure what I've done but I've tried restarting Visual Studio and it's still grayed out.

[image]

Debugging isn't running.

Why is it grayed out and how to re-enable it again?

Comment: Suddenly it re-enabled itself... Not the first time this happens and it's very annoying.

Comment: I found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251788/visual-studio-search-solution-explorer-is-disabled